# Report formatting errors with DataComPy output

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a report to compare two dataframes, validating a data migration was performed correctly between an old and new warehouse using the DataComPy function for pandas in Python/via Jupyter Notebooks. All is working properly, except the report is refusing to publish with the correct formatting.

Here are the first few lines of my output:

`DataComPy Comparison\n--------------------\n\nDataFrame Summary\n-----------------\n\n  DataFrame  Columns    Rows\n0       df1       56  340985\n1       df2       56  340985\n\nColumn Summary\n--------------\n\nNumber of columns in common: 56\nNumber of columns in df1 but not in df2: 0\nNumber of columns in df2 but not in df1: 0\n\nRow Summary\n-----------\n\nMatched on: braze_id, segment_name\nAny duplicates on match values: No\nAbsolute Tolerance: 0\nRelative Tolerance: 0\nNumber of rows in common: 340,985\nNumber of rows in df1 but not in df2: 0\nNumber of rows in df2 but not in df1: 0\n\nNumber of rows with some compared columns unequal: 9\nNumber of rows with all compared columns equal: 340,976\n\nColumn Comparison\n-----------------\n\nNumber of columns compared with some values unequal: 8\nNumber of columns compared with all values equal: 48\nTotal number of values which compare unequal: 20\n\nColumns with Unequal Values or Types\n------------------------------------\n\n`

I would like to get the report in the following format:

[image]

Comment: Is this _"output"_ assigned to a variable?  If so, have you tried `print(that_variable)`?